How should a stationary suspended spherical tube be modified to incorporate aerodynamic downforce mitigating both fore and aft 45 mph - 120 mph winds?
The question involves this topic; High-wind rollover damage in center-pivot irrigation systems. This study involves the additive engineering possibilities to achieving an aerodynamic remedy essentially mitigating tip-over instances during extreme storm events. Focus should be on the suspended conduit fluid-transfer system, which is the spherical tube in question.

spherical means shaped like a ball

Did you mean cylindrical tube - circular cross section?

My immediate reaction would be to worry less about creating downforce, and more about  minimizing drag. If you create much downforce, you're going to need to strengthen the rest of the design to carry the extra load the wind will generate.

If there is a shape that is causing aero loads you do not want, remove it to zero the loads. Did you need your shape to actually do something? If so, what? And what pieces of the shape contribute most and least to that purpose?
